# Docker image weighs too much

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a small Node.js app. The whole directory weighs 212 KB.

I dockerized the app and saved the image as a tar. The saved tar weighs 663 MB.

Why does the image weigh so much?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node bin/www
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: how many layer does it have??

Comment: and how are you creating the docker Image??

Comment: can you post your docker file

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ is every folder in the tar a layer? If so, I have 12 layers.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ like that: docker build -t hello-express .

Comment: Use node:alpine image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/), this package is based on the image `buildpack-deps` which is a common Debian dependency image. According to it's [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/), it "includes a large number of development header packages", which means it ships a ton of common dependencies

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `node:7-alpine`.

Alpine is a version of Linux created to have lighter Docker images.

The 'normal' Docker images of `node:7` come with a lot of 'junk' you don't use in production, like Vim, Zip, etc.